# Topologically transforming a line into a circle

Tags: functions

I'm a little confused in my understanding of continuous topological functions.  In the link below(I can't have it embedded since I'm new) the bottom left picture is what I am trying to understand. Is that technically a continuous function by transforming a line into an open circle. I understand that a line could technically be a part of a circle of radius infinity, but would forming this circle create the inside genus? Or am I horribly misunderstanding this?

[topological analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybb6x.png)

[image]

Comment: No one asked me, but such questions highly depend on how $f$ is defined, so if the picture is all you have to go on....

Comment: Also, functions $f: X \to Y$ take points in $X$ associate them to points in $Y$, sometimes by drastic means (like constants).  So, this doesn't necessarily mean that $f$ is building $Y$ out of $X$ or topologically transforming $X$ into $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the diagram itself is not a valid definition for a function. There are continuous functions $\Bbb R\to S^1$, and there are discontinuous functions  $\Bbb R\to S^1$ as well.

Assuming that you are just wrapping the line around the circle infinitely many times, your function is e.g. $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ and is continuous (although not injective).

Assuming that you are wrapping the line once, but missing one point, again this is a continuous function, e.g. $x\mapsto e^{2i\tan^{-1}(x)}$. There, you are missing one point ($-1$), so the mapping is not surjective.

It is impossible for a mapping $\Bbb R\to S^1$ to be all three at once continuous, injective, and surjective.

---

Note: the formulas given are just examples, since all you have is a picture, a lot of topologically equivalent formulas would be possible in each of the above situations.

Comment: "There, you are missing one point (−1), so the mapping is not injective." *surjective

Answer (score 0):

Is that a line, or a line *segment*? Treating a line as a circle of infinite radius would mean that the pre-image of one of the points on the circle would be +- infinity, which is are not valid points in traditional geometry. A line can be taken to a circle continuously by taking e^ix, but that is not injective.